# Unfortunately App has stopped but colud not find the logcat

Tags: android-studio-3.0

[logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9deYp.png)

Unfortunately app has stopped. When i checked the logcat there is no information displayed related to this issue. how i could fix this. please help me

Comment: add activity code herer

Comment: Now i got the logcat.